# open directory from a notification bar

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications

well am downloading a file from Url in background and showing the process in notification  and the downloaded file are getting  stored into downloaded folder ,  i want to open the download  folder( directory ) when user taps on the notification bar , how can i do this ?? this is what i tried but its not doing anything  even no errors in logcat :

```
DownloadFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(DownloadFolder), "file/*");
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

the download folder is a path to android's download directory, any idea what am doin wrong because i have no clue , any guidance  would be so helpful for me

Thanks

Comment: Folder opens, but clicking on the file, It's not opening.
got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this intent action : `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);`